# How to remove unwanted background processes?

Tags: itunes, process, services, optimize

Since I installed iTunes to manage an iPhone 3GS and the software manager for a Motorola Droid smartphone, I have the below processes run all the time:

[image: screenshot]

How can I remove the processes so they do not run all the time in the background?

I'm using Windows XP Home with the latest iTunes and Motorola software manager.

Comment: The simple solution is you remove both of peices of software.  Sometimes the obvious answer is the only answer.  You can also simply disable the service(s) in question.

Comment: The best solution is to stop processes to work, like @Devid wrote in hes answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type ***services.msc*** and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. From here find the services and change the settings from automatic to manual. Also type in ***Windows Search*** autostart and check what programs are in that folder, remove the ones you don't want to run when your computer is starting up.

Go and download ***Process Hacker*** from [**here**](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/). It is a better Task-Manager. You can then just kill the processes you don't want or stop the services. Be careful not to stop some important services or processes which are needed for your computer to run normally.

Download ***Autoruns*** from [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). You can see more services and stop them from auto running on your PC.

Open iTunes and the software manager and check in the options. Good programs give you the option to turn off process when not in use.

***Advice:*** Upgrade from Windows XP to Windows 7, cause Microsoft won`t be supporting  XP anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you run msconfig you can use the 'Services' and 'Startup' tabs to control what starts automatically with Windows. Clicking "Hide all Microsoft services" on the 'Services' tab will give you a shorter list to look through.